# Separate some values by brackets and decrease a number from a column to another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, substitution, vba

I have an input with these values in different columns:

```
First column   Second Column    Third column
72              54,72            35,43
63              63,70,74         41
39              32,39,49         51
```

From this table I need an output like this:

```
First_output   Second_output      Third_output
50              54,35,43          [50,54][54][35,43]
50              70,74,41          [50,70,74][70,74][41]
50              32,49,51          [50,32,49][32,49][51]
```

First_output I made it with if(First column>100,First column,50),
 second_output and third_output is a little headache for me, I've tried something with concatenate, but I couldn't get rid of First column for different scenarios.

RULES:

- First_output will become 50 in place of 72,63,39
- Second_output will become Second Column&Third column concatenated
  but without numbers that are in first column (which are 72,63,39)
- Third_output will become, in brackets: first brackets contains second
  column, but as I said 72,63,39 will become 50 and that's why I have
  those numbers, second brackets contain same numbers without 50, third brackets contain third column.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the 2nd and 3rd?

Comment: I'm not seeing a pattern in your output data. Where do the numbers come from?

Comment: basically first column is changing with 50, if i have 2 numbers in third column i will need to put them in brackets at the end of third_column, i need to git rid for instance in first row of first column which i will change to number 50, and in second_column i need to concatenate both second column and third column but without first column number

Comment: PLEASE WRITE THE RULLES, its totally unclear what column 2 and 3 should be ,

Comment: @AndreiVieru you are happy to use vba?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `First column` is in A1, not VBA, in D2:

```
50
```

in E2:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2&","&C2,A2,","),",,,",","),",,","")
```

in F2:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("[50,"&SUBSTITUTE(B2,A2,"")&"]["&SUBSTITUTE(B2,A2,"")&"]["&C2&"]",",,",","),",]","]"),"[,","[")
```

and copy all three down to suit.